# Issue with respect to Scrapy due to Meta Refresh

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

I am new to Scrapy framework and am trying to crawl a website using Spider. In my website, while i navigate from Page 1 -> Page 2, intermediate page is added with Meta Refresh which redirects the it to Page 2. However i am constantly getting the Error 302 while redirecting. I tried following things

Setting the User Agent to "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36"

Setting DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 15

Setting REDIRECT_MAX_METAREFRESH_DELAY = 100

However i had no success. I am new to Scrapy. I would appreciate if someone helps me to provide the direction on how to resolve this issue.

Adding logs as per request

```
2017-02-17 21:02:43 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2017-02-17 21:02:43 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pag
es/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2017-02-17 21:02:43 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening o
n 127.0.0.1:6023
2017-02-17 21:02:44 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://xxxx.website.com/search-cases.htm> (referer: None)
2017-02-17 21:02:44 [quotes] INFO: http://www.xxxx.website2.com/e
services/home.page
2017-02-17 21:02:46 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (
meta refresh) to <GET http://www.xxxx.website2.com/eservices/;jsessionid=D
724B51CE14CFB9A06AB5A1C2BADC7BA?x=pQSPWmZkMdOltOc6jey5Pzm2g*gqQrsim1X*85dDjm1K*V
wIS*xP-fdT9lRZBHHOA41kK1OaAco2dC8Un6N*uJtWnK50mGmm> from <GET http://www.courtre
cords.alaska.gov/eservices/home.page>
2017-02-17 21:02:55 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (
302) to <GET http://www.xxxx.website2.com/eservices/home.page> from <GET h
ttp://www.xxxx.website2.com/eservices/;jsessionid=D724B51CE14CFB9A06AB5A1C
2BADC7BA?x=pQSPWmZkMdOltOc6jey5Pzm2g*gqQrsim1X*85dDjm1K*VwIS*xP-fdT9lRZBHHOA41kK
1OaAco2dC8Un6N*uJtWnK50mGmm>
2017-02-17 21:02:55 [scrapy.dupefilters] DEBUG: Filtered duplicate request: <GET
 http://www.xxxx.website2.com/eservices/home.page> - no more duplicates wi
ll be shown (see DUPEFILTER_DEBUG to show all duplicates)
2017-02-17 21:02:55 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
```

** Please note that i have changed website name **

Comment: share the error logs please

Comment: Its not because of met refresh ... please post your scrapy logs so we can help

Comment: @eLRuLL I have shared the logs and have made changes to actual website name.

Comment: there is a redirection, which later is filtered (because of being a duplicated request)

Comment: @eLRuLL Thanks. I made dont_filter = True for redirection request and it helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @eLRuLL mentioned in his comment, problem was that duplicate request was being filtered. After making **dont_filter = True** for redirection request, program started scraping properly